# how to add java modules to .net application

Tags: java, .net, angularjs, single-sign-on

We have an application built in .net, and we want add all new modules with java (angularjs, spring...) , so we want to do single sign on between all modules (java and .net), and we must keep the same menu in all modules (and all user data (department,roles...)), so what is the best solution to do that please?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Jasig/cas

Comment: we are already think on this solution, but for the shared data (MENU,...) problem how can we handle that?